# How to get custom fields from my WooCommerce product tag terms?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

Using Advanced Custom Fields plugin, I have added an "Image" custom field to my WooCommerce product tags.

Now I’m using the following to get the attached product tag term to my products

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );
```

But I am unable to get my "Image" custom field.

How can I get the image custom fields from my WooCommerce product tag terms?

Answer (score 0):

First in the ACF settings for the image field, be sure that you have selected **"Image ID"** in **Return format** option:

[image]

You will use the following from a dynamic `$product_id` variable, to get and display the attached image of your WooCommerce product tag terms:

```
$product_tag_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_tag' );

foreach ( $product_tag_terms as $term ) {
    $image_id = get_field( 'image', $term );
    
    if ( ! empty($image_id) && is_numeric($image_id) ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id );

        echo $image; // Output
    }
}
```

Tested and works.

ACF Documentation: [Adding fields to a taxonomy term](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)